# How to have a volume control/widget in Awesome WM?

Tags: sound, awesome

Simple question but hard answer, i searched around in Google a solution to make a dynamic widget to control and see the volume with Awesome Window manager but i can't find a working solution.

Any one got a solution to this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I simply followed the tutorial at [http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Volume_control_and_display](http://web.archive.org/web/20130928001745/http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Volume_control_and_display) and it worked. However, volume control was only via keyboard. Is this what you were looking for?

I should note that I'm on debian (testing) which I think uses awesome 3.4.

**-- Update:** After some testing out, I found [http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Farhavens_volume_widget](http://web.archive.org/web/20130928001745/http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Farhavens_volume_widget), which has mouse controls (scroll mouse to control volume, and click to toggle mute). Following the tutorial works on my box.

Comment: Works great except the mute function, it mutes my sound but another click don't unmute it ...

Comment: Same, but it's a bug with amixer I think; https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/878986. For me the command `amixer sset Master toggle` or `amixer -d pulse set Master 1+ togglemute` both work to toggle mute.

Comment: So to get the click to work, insert your working command in the line starting with io.popen (in the else statement, in the volume function). For example, my line for that is `io.popen("amixer -D pulse set Master 1+ togglemute"):read("*all")` (Mistake in the previous comment which I cannot edit anymore: should be `amixer -D` not `amixer -d`).

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to mention following implementations just in case somebody is interested to have a volume control widget compatible with Awesome WM 4+:

[image: screenshot]

From left to right:

- [volume widget](https://github.com/streetturtle/awesome-wm-widgets/tree/master/volume-widget)
- [volumebar-widget](https://github.com/streetturtle/awesome-wm-widgets/tree/master/volumebar-widget)
- [volumearc-widget](https://github.com/streetturtle/awesome-wm-widgets/tree/master/volumearc-widget)

All three widgets support mouse control: scroll up/down - increases/decreases volume, click - toggles mute.

Comment: Much better answer with newer awesomes.

Answer (score 4):

If you have media keys you can use this

```
awful.key({}, "XF86AudioRaiseVolume", function () awful.util.spawn("amixer -D pulse sset Master 2%+", false) end),
awful.key({}, "XF86AudioLowerVolume", function () awful.util.spawn("amixer -D pulse sset Master 2%-", false) end),
awful.key({}, "XF86AudioMute", function () awful.util.spawn("amixer -D pulse sset Master toggle", false) end),
```

in globalkeys in your rc.lua script

Comment: This was pretty much exactly what I needed, thanks. The only thing is on the lower volume I needed to change the "+" to a "-", otherwise volume down would increase the volume.

Comment: Noted, i have edited it

Answer (score 1):

[volumeicon](https://github.com/Maato/volumeicon) worked out of the box for me. Note that this is not an AwesomeWM widget but a standalone project written in C. The advantage of this over the Awesome widgets are:

- can use mouse to interact with widget and adjust volume (scroll wheel or dragging volume bar)
- works out of the box with PulseAudio and multiple output sinks
- configurable notifications when volume is adjusted (GTK+-style or FreeDesktop-style notifications, or none at all)
- opens a mixer of your choice on middle click

---

If you'd prefer a pure Lua Awesome widget, here is a list of available ones:

- [awesome-zen](https://github.com/atsepkov/awesome-zen/blob/master/widgets/volume/)
- [streetturltle](https://github.com/streetturtle/awesome-wm-widgets) widgets (3 styles: [1](https://github.com/streetturtle/awesome-wm-widgets/tree/master/volume-widget), [2](https://github.com/streetturtle/awesome-wm-widgets/tree/master/volumearc-widget), [3](https://github.com/streetturtle/awesome-wm-widgets/tree/master/volumebar-widget))
- [lain](https://github.com/lcpz/lain) (2 styles: [1](https://github.com/lcpz/lain/blob/master/widget/pulse.lua), [2](https://github.com/lcpz/lain/blob/master/widget/pulsebar.lua))
- [vicious](https://github.com/vicious-widgets/vicious/blob/master/widgets/volume_linux.lua)
- [blingbling](https://github.com/cedlemo/blingbling/blob/master/volume.lua)
- [obvious](https://github.com/hoelzro/obvious/blob/master/volume_alsa/init.lua)